# Possible to rotate the map? Heading? Windows Phone 7, Bing Maps

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

Is it possible to rotate the map or heading?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a `RotateTransform` as the `RenderTransform` for the `Map` control in the same way that you can to any control.

Comment: yup, this worked well. incresed the size of the map so you don't see the edges when it rotates

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you want the map to do the equivalent of always facing North, regardless of which way the phone is facing.

This is not possible as it would require access to a compass (or magnetometer) and no such functionality is available to 3rd party apps.

All but one devices released have a compass (apparently) but the need for one was removed from the chassis-1 spec late last year. I believe, the built in maps app supports the functionality you're after. Could you call out to that?

Comment: will have to be using the heading out of what the gps tells when there is movent

Answer (score 0):

How about supporting landscape mode on your page so if you want the map and heading rotated you rotate the phone.